# Instantiate Tab bar Controller without Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In all other instances I'm using a segue to transition to a tab bar controller, but I have a need now to load up a tab bar controller without a segue.  To do this with a regular view I would use this:

```
EditProfileView *view = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editProfileView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

The EditProfileView is one of the tabs on my tab controller.  How do I change this so that it loads all the tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should push the UITabBarController instead.
e.g.

```
UITabBarController *tc = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabbarcontroller"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tc animated:YES];
```

Make sure the tabbarcontroller's storyboard ID is the same

Also, if you want to present one particular viewcontroller:

```
[tc setSelectedViewController:[tc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]];
```